# jQuery on function not firing in mustache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am using `$(Mustache.to_html` to render a template on my webpage - if I check the actual html rendered on the page it is as below:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-template">
<tr data-name="{{name}}">
    <td>
    <select id="titlesDropDown" name="SelectedTitleId"><option value="">--Select Title--</option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Miss</option>
    <option value="3">Mrs/Corporate</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Age" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that I want to trigger a function when the title dropdown is changed.  In doc ready I added the below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('#titlesDropDown').on('change', function () {           
        alert('Dropdown change fired');
    });
});
```

Is there something else which I need to do to wire the change event up to a mustache rendered template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are using delegation, but it is again on a dynamically generated node.

Try this instead:

```
 $(document).on('change', ''#titlesDropDown'', function () {
```

Or, alternatively, you can just replace `document` with an element present in the DOM at the time of load.

Comment: You could, no harm, but you dont have to.. if you use `document`, it does not have to be wrapped with the `document.ready`